# dataframe results are not returned while reading csv file

Tags: csv, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

[image: Query result output attached]I m trying to read a csv file, below is the code i used , its not returning any results. In the specified path , the csv file has data in it. I had some issue when i used `ValidFile = spark.read.csv(ValidationFileDest, header = True)` , for this the result is returned but the data for the columns were interchanges and nulls were assinged thats the reason i applied mode DROPMALFORMED in my code. But it is not returning any result.

```
parquetextension=".parquet"
BronzeStage_Path = "dbfs:/mnt/bronze/stage/" +parentname+"/" +filename
#validated_path="dbfs:/mnt/bronze/landing/ClaimDenialsSouce/"+parentname+"/"+"current/"+"Valid/"+todayDate+"_"+"CDAValidFile"+extension
# df_sourcefilevalid.repartition(1).write.format(write_format).option("header", "true").save(BronzeStagePath)
# ValidFileSrc_BS= get_csv_files(exception_path)
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .master("local") \
  .appName("parquet_example") \
  .getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.csv.parser.columnPruning.enabled",False)
ValidFile = spark.read.format('csv').option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load(ValidationFileDest)
display(ValidFile)
```

[image: csv file data]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check if you are providing the correct file path or the variable of your CSV file. I have repro'd in our environment and was able read the CSV file without any issue

**Reading CSV file :**

```
filepath="dbfs:/FileStore/test11-1.csv"
df11 = spark.read.format("csv").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").option("header", "true").load(filepath)
display(df11)
```

[image: Ref1]